# Ack doesn't seem to use its whitelist

Tags: command-line, ack

I have `ack` 2.04 and it searches not only files in its whitelist but everything - logs, text, tags.

```
$ echo 'needle' | tee haystack.txt haystack haystack.log

$ ack needle
haystack
1:needle

haystack.log
1:needle

haystack.txt
1:needle

$ ack --version
ack 2.04 (git commit 8f405b7)
Running under Perl 5.12.4 at /usr/bin/perl
```

There's no `~/.ackrc` and `ack --dump` produces a bunch of directives marked as default. Any ideas aside from manually making it ignore unneeded files?

Comment: Please remember to include your OS. Is this Unix? Linux? OSX? Cygwin? Bash running on Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ack changed some core behaviour since version 2.0. The most important change is that by default ack 2 searches in all non-binary files.

From the [website](http://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.0/):

> GENERAL CHANGES
>
> When no selectors are specified, ack 1.x only searches through files that it can map to a file type. ack 2.x, by constrast, will
>   search through every regular, non-binary file that is not explicitly
>   ignored via --ignore-file or --ignore-dir. This is similar to the
>   behavior of the -a/--all option in ack 1.x.
>
> REMOVED OPTIONS
>
> Because of the change in default search behavior, the -a/--all and -u/--unrestricted options have been removed. In addition, the -k/--known-types option was added to cause ack to behave with the default search behavior of ack 1.x.